# How to add multiple links in excel cell?

Tags: excel, cell

When I use ALT+ENTER I get multiple lines of text and could not format them as links. Is there any way to get multiple links in one excel cell?

Answer (score 4):

You can use shapes that you can assign with a hyperlink. See https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/916-excel-insert-multiple-hyperlinks.html

1. Via insert, you can choose a rectangular shape, insert this in the
   cell.
2. Right click the shape and choose 'Hyperlink' and type the
   address.
3. Go to step 1 until enough hyperlinks are created.

Comment: Either you cannot insert a shape IN a cell, or this answer should explain how.

Comment: This is important because if you simply put that shape over a cell, it will desync as soon as a new row is added above, rending this trick worse that not doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Links are tight to cells in Excel, the first link that it detects is the default link for a cell. You can still put :
First link (Alt +Enter), Second Link

But Still only when clicking on the cell, you will be directed to the first link.
As the "links" formatting is map with the cell and no with the text.