# How to insert multiple hyperlinks in the same cell

Tags: node.js, exceljs

How can I add multiple hyperlink lines into the same cell using excelJS

https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs

For instance: one cell would hold Google \n Gmail as hyper links

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible with exceljs.

This can't even be done in a straightforward way in Excel. Excel only adds hyper links to whole cells.

There is a hacky way of accomplishing it in Excel by inserting shapes and adding hyper links to those shapes ([see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709056/how-to-add-multiple-links-in-excel-cell)). But exceljs doesn't provide a way to draw shapes in cells.