# Adding more than one hyperlink in same Excel Cell using phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I want to have more than one hyperlink in same excel cell using phpspreadsheet

```
Column1    Column2
___________________

Cell1      Link1
___________________
Cell2      Link1
           Link2
           Link3
___________________
```

I tried write it as following

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(28, $i,"=HYPERLINK('http://www.google.co.uk','GOOGLE')&CHAR(10)&HYPERLINK('http://www.amazon.co.uk','AMAZON')");
```

but the generated excel file isn't readable by excel, I know how to put only one hyperlink using

```
$sheet->setCellValue('1'.'1', 'Showfile');
$sheet->getCell('A'.1)->getHyperlink()->setUrl('http://localhost/upload/'.$strFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have more than one hyperlink in a cell in Excel. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/multiple-hyperlinks-in-a-cell/0dbf112c-3e21-4d2d-98ca-bf6e8e10a6eb

Also see [How to add multiple links in excel cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709056/how-to-add-multiple-links-in-excel-cell)